# how I can store some arrays in a 2 dimension vector?

Tags: c++

I have a loop in each iterate an array is printed. now I need this array so I want to put them in a 2 dimension vector. I wrote this code but I dont know why it does not work!

when I run it does not print any thing and it dont show any error!

```
int main() {
  int i, u;
  const int j = 9;
  vector<vector<int>> V;
  int B[9] = {};
  for (int r = 0; r<10; r++) {
    B[r] = 1;
    for (int t = 0; t<V.size(); t++) {
      for (int w = 0; w<j; w++, u++) {
        V[t][w] = B[u];
      }
    }
  }
  for (int m = 0; m<V.size(); m++) {
    for (int k = 0; k<j; k++) {
      cout << "V=" << " " << V[m][k];
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

For example in the first loop in each iterate B changes and I want to store all of them in a matrix! for example  I have:

first iterate:  B=(1,0,0)

second iterate: B=(0,1,0)

third iterate: B=(0,0,1)

now I want to have:

```
V={{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}}
```

Comment: Where are the arrays? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47096091/edit) your post to include the relevant code.

Comment: That is some seriously "funky" indentation you have there...

Comment: B is  array. my code is long should I put all of it?

Comment: You should take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [the help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Borgleader what u mean?

Comment: @shere no, don't put the whole code, only the relevant parts that may help us to understand what exactly you want. The question as it stands here cannot be answered, there is not enough information. Especially _B is an array.and V is 2 dimension vector_ is very unclear. Don't describe the code, show it.

Comment: You're likely looking for push_back() on vectors

Comment: @MichaelWalz I edited with a small code

Comment: @lorro not really please see edite

Comment: why V is empty?

Comment: The variable `u` is never initialized.

Comment: @ I want to fill it out with B

Comment: @shere I still think you are. Vectors won't resize themselves on indexing and you haven't used .resize() or constructed for a specific size.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and shown us what output you expect.

Comment: @MichaelWalz see example please

Comment: Don't post _"it does not work"_ without explaining **how** it does not work: what it should do, what it did instead, and the full text/line/column of any error that appeared.

Comment: so.. you have B = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1] and you want V v[0] -> : 1 0 0, v[1] -> 0 1 0, v[2] -> 0 0 1?

Comment: @Taz742 no! I gave an example above I have B=(1,0,0) , B=(0,1,0), B=(0,0,1) I want V= {{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}}

Comment: @underscore_d when I run it does not print any thing and it dont show any error!

Comment: wtf. how print it anything, when you dont create anything? 
where the V size, push_back, B ? do you know what is vector<vector<T> > ?

Comment: @Taz742 so how I can push_back each array as a row to the matrix V?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that you have N `int[N]` values, and you want 1 `vector<vector<int>>` value.

```
std::vector<int> fromArray(int (&B)[N])
{
    return { std::begin(B), std::end(B) };
}
```

This is a function that will turn a 1D array into a 1D vector. you will need to call it N times.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> fromArrays(int (&Bs)[N][N])
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> result{ N };
    std::transform(std::begin(Bs), std::end(Bs), result.begin(), fromArray);
    return result;
}
```

Here we take a 2D array and turn it into a 2D vector. This requires you have all the `B`s together.

```
int main()
{
    constexpr int N = 3;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> V;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        int B[N] = {};
        B[i] = 1;
        V.emplace_back(fromArray(B));
    }

    for (std::vector<int> & v : V) 
    {
        for (int i : v) 
        {
            std::cout << i << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Alternately, if you don't have all the `B`s all in one go, just loop N times getting one `B`

Comment: thanks! its a little high level! I get some error like:  invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript

Comment: @shere  
What are you using for N? `constexpr int N = 3;` above the function definitions should work for your 3 x 3 example

Comment: i used constexpr int N=3 but still get error:  Statement has no effect 'std::vector<std::vector<int>>'

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this:

```
int main() {
  const int Bsize = 9;
  const int NumberOfLines = 4;    // number of iterations

  int B[Bsize] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };

  vector<vector<int>> V;

  V.resize(NumberOfLines);
  int bIndex = 0;

  for (int r = 0; r < NumberOfLines; r++) {

    // add code that changes B here

    V[r].resize(Bsize);

    for (int w = 0; w < Bsize; w++) {
        V[r][w] = B[w];
    }
  }

  for (int m = 0; m < V.size(); m++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < V[m].size(); k++) {
      cout << " " << V[m][k];
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

In this sample we'll generate 4 lines (one for each iteration), but `B` is each time the same here. If you want B to change between each iteration, you need to insert the corresponding code that changes `B`.

The output of the sample will be:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: If it was necessary. what is it B massive ? :d

Comment: B is not like this! It just was a sample! B has 1000 element. I want to put each array to matrix as a row. ! If I could write V with hand it was easy

Comment: @shere are the two dimensions of `V` always equal? Otherwise said: is `V` a square matrice?

Comment: @shere and what exactly is `B`? Is it a one dimensional array or a two dimensional array? This line in your question (`B=(1,0,0) B=(0,1,0) B=(0,0,1)`) suggests the latter.

Comment: B is 1 dimension array! its output. in each iterate B changes. I want to store all of them in the matrix. so in each iterate B is gonna be a row of the matrix!

Comment: I'm still not quite sure if I understood, but using the program in my answer you should be able to figure out what to do.

Answer (score 0):

If guessing, there is a my implementation:

```
int main() {
    int len = 9;
    int div = 3;
    int total = len / div;

    int B[len]={1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1};

    vector<vector<int> > V(total);

    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len && cnt < total; i += div) {
        for (int j = i; j < i + div; j++) {
            V[cnt].push_back(B[j]);
        }cnt++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < V[i].size(); j++) {
            cout << V[i][j] << " ";
        }cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

V is like this:

```
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
```

Comment: no B is not like this! B is an array that is output! in each iterate B changes and I want to store all of them in the matrix as a row.